# Login Form Style

Tags: css, pug

I am trying to build a login form, however the submit button, remember me checkbox, and remember me label are not being properly formatted. Currently, the label is on the left, and then the submit button and checkbox. I would like it so that the label and checkbox appear after the submit button. I am using Jade for the template engine. I would also like the solution to work properly on mobile browsers.

```
Jade
doctype html
html
head
    title
        | Log In
    meta(charset = "UTF-8")
    meta(name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0")
    link(rel = "stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/login.css")
body
    form#logIn(name = "logIn", method = "post", action = "/login")
        p#loginMessage Title
        label(for = "handle") Username:
        input#handle(type = "text", required = "required", name = "handle" maxlength = "20" value = handle)
        br
        br
        label(for="pass") Password:
        input#password(type = "password", required = "required", maxlength = "60" name = "pass")
        br
        br
        div#submitDiv
            button#submit(name = "submit") SUBMIT!
            label#rememberMe(for = "rememberMeCheckbox") Remember Me:
        input#rememberMeCheckbox(type = "checkbox", name = "remember")
        br
        br
        div#errorMessage #{errorMessage}


CSS

#loginMessage {
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
form {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: .875em; /*14*/
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #FBFF06;
    background: #EFBA00;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3.125em; /*50*/
    -moz-border-radius: 3.125em;
    border-radius: 3.125em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    width: 50%;
}
#errorMessage {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
div#submitDiv {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
button#submit {
    width: 10%;
    background: #FBFF06;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #BC8507;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
label#rememberMe {
    width: 15%;
}
input#rememberMeCheckbox {
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: But what is not working in mobiles exactly (which differs from a desktop browser)?

Comment: do you have a js fiddle?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xuqssL84/) @GuilhermeNascimento My problem is that the order of the button, label, and checkbox are currently messed up. I want it to be: Submit, label, checkbox. There is currently no error with mobile browsers, however I am trying to incorporate responsive web design and want to make sure that it will work on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your label has a float: left style applied to it which is why it's not displaying in the same order as your HTML. 
You need to remove the float for just that label and display it as inline to keep everything all on the same line.

```
label#rememberMe {
    width: 10%;
    float: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ap68p5zg/1/

I also added a min-width to your Submit button so it won't cut off the text and a margin for alignment.

```
button#submit {
    width: 10%;
    background: #FBFF06;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #BC8507;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 3%;
    min-width: 75px;
}
```